# http to https redirection using .htaccess not working

Tags: .htaccess, ubuntu, apache2, redirect

I want to redirect  http://myip/admin    to https://myip/admin.  I am trying to use .htaccess to do this (want this only for the admin folder).

Contents of .htaccess placed in the relevant folder:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

(apache mod_rewrite is enabled).  Both http://myip/admin  and https://myip/admin are visible (but the redirection does not work). Server is Ubuntu.

I have tried few variations of the above rules from the internet but no luck :(

Any inputs would be appreciated.

regards,
JP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it and learnt something new. The AllowOverride option in apache's main config file was not set correctly.

Also, if someone faces such issues 2 points:
1) apache reload may sometime not work as expected. Try restart
2) Clear browser cache and / or refresh page.