# Missing redirection to HTTPS

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, apache2

i install on my LAMP SSL certificates with Let´s encrypt. I want to redirect all my Domains through HTTPS.
Now its working, but not completely.

http://domain.name redirect to https://domain.name (Certificate works)
http://www.domain.name dont redirecting to https:// , but directly https://www.domain.name (Certificate works)

There´s my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the Problem with this Thread
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3869287/8341397

I set in the /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

All AllowOverride from None to All and restart Apache2-Service